# Pivot table formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have several pivot tables and formatted the color and fonts. When I change the filter or add any data, I lose the formatting. I have tried going to pivot options and selecting preserve formatting, it doesn't work for me. Please help if anyone knows the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Pivot tables format themselves. Any formatting you apply will be lost. I have only been able to consistently apply post formatting using VBA. If you want examples, you will need to post an example of your raw data and your pivot.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use conditional formatting instead of formatting individual cells. I have a pivot table that tracks if deadlines are missed:

[image: Pivot Formatting]

Select a cell you want to format, go to conditional formatting, and click on "New Rule". Then, you can select which cells you want to format (in my case, the second option), chose your criteria (for me it was if the date is greater than the column next to it on the left), and set your formatting.

My formatting remains regardless of what I add to the table. If you add different columns or cells you want to apply rules to, you'll need to create new formatting rules for those. But, if your columns are fairly consistant, this might do the trick.

Comment: Added to which you can use a formula for a rule which always evaluates to True eg =1=1, so you always format that selected data the same.

Answer (score 0):

To properly apply formatting to PivotTables you need to tell it what you are selecting, otherwise it's just applied to the underlying cells and often then thrown away when refreshing or changing layouts.

Select something you want to format, eg Grand Totals, or one specific category. In the PivotTables ribbon group, on the Analyze ribbon, in the Actions group click Select. Then choose what to "select" - do you want to format the label, or the data values, or both? Now apply your format - colour, bold, number format or whatever. This should now "stick" to that selection, even if you rearrange your PT (switching rows for columns for example, or adding a level of breakdown to the rows, the same category should still be bold).