# How to maintain pivot chart format after refresh?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-chart

As I created a pivot chart, I applied format to the chart, such as changing color of some series.

However, when clicking on **refresh**, the format goes back to the default colors.

How can I maintain the chart format after refresh?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1177615/pivot-table-formatting), and this article about [maintaining pivot table formatting](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T008731_Maintaining_Formatting_when_Refreshing_PivotTables.html) might help, but without knowing your specific problem I can't say it will work for your table. If you're able to post a screenshot, or give more detail as to what you're trying to accomplish, I can probably give a better answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for the chart though. But the bug/behavior seems to depend on which menu the color was changed from. Select series and right click change outline on pop-up menu -> will change on refresh. Select series and Format Selection in Format context menu, change color -> will remain on refresh.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Sounds like you solved your problem though, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Select the data series in your pivot chart.  Right click and select Format Data Series...
Select the color option (paint bucket), and select solid fill (or whatever you want), but the key is to select something other than automatic.  Set the colors you want.  Save the file, exit (not sure exiting is necessary, but you can find out for yourself), open the file, refresh your pivot table(s) and your formatting should remain as you last set it.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue too. What you'll need to do is right click the chart element within the chart itself (i.e. if a bar chart then right click on the bars themselves) and edit the colour directly in the pop up at the top of the right-click menu that appears (rather than in the Format Data Series menu that you can get in the side panel of the workbook). 
Don't know why this works but somehow editing the colour here made it stop resetting to automatic colours when clicking different slicer buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the pivot chart series formatting changing when i added a filter or useda slicer. I had a combo graph and the series style kept altering from line to stacked bar.

My solution was to add some VBA code to the worksheet. My code is below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlColumnStacked
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection("Limit").ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.Deselect
End Sub
```

The first line in the code executes the code block each time the sheet recalculates. My code was throwing errors when it tried to format the "limit" timeseries. Adding the line "On Error Resume Next" means that if it threw an error the code would move on and continue.

To add this to the worksheet, **Right click** on the worksheet tab and click **view code**.

Paste the VBA code into the sheet, save and close the editor. Try refreshing the chart. If it throws errors you may have to debug a few times.

If you're not comfortable writing code you can create the code by recording a macro, and copying and pasting the code into the worksheet tab as described above. It will also help you find the names or id's of objects.

i just had a play and got the following example working. it selects a chart time series and colours it green.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Select
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    End With
    ActiveChart.Deselect
End Sub
```