# How to lock the format of a pivot chart

Tags: vba, formatting, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I have a pivot chart from a group of data, and I need to show it in a specific type of different charts (combo charts) and giving every bar and lines a specific color. The problem is that every time a filter my pivot table on a different way or if I close my excel and open it again, all the format disappears.

I have tried making a regular chart from the table and although it does keep the format, it wont work or show what I want when filtering my pivot table (since the cells position may vary). I've also tried duplicating the data of the pivot table to a normal table but the result is the same as the mentioned above.

Does anybody have a trick for this? a different way to try? Maybe a VBA code that locks the format of the chart?

Comment: I'm no expert in pivot-stuff, so I'm not sure exactly what you want to do without a bunch of pictures and examples. But I do know that there's basically nothing that you can't do with VBA.
So if you do the formatting you need with a macro, you should just be able to re-apply it if the formatting disappears.

Comment: Also did you check out the following links: [Link1](https://superuser.com/questions/1303061/how-to-maintain-pivot-chart-format-after-refresh) - [Link2](https://superuser.com/questions/1177615/pivot-table-formatting) and [Link3](https://peltiertech.com/pivot-chart-formatting-changes/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Click on your chart, then go to Format (related to your chart), select one of the shape styles (bottom of the list) for example red fill with white font text.
Then if you want to keep fill white or none, just sell still in format different color of shape fill.
And voila the text won't change font color anymore.